# Using modulus to return a shape back to canvas after passing its borders

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I used to use two ways to return a shape back to a canvas when this shape is moving from left to right, those ways are using **if / else** statement and using **modulus**.

For example (using JavaScript):

```
function Shape(size, movement){
    this.size  = size;
    this.pos_x = Math.random()*500;
    this.pos_y = Math.random()*500;
    this.movement = movement;
};

var shape1 = new Shape(5, 2);
var shape2 = new Shape(5, 4);

// first way to move a shape from left to right and return it to the canvas.
if(shape1.pos_x < canvas.width){
        shape1.pos_x += shape1.movement;
}else {shape1.pos_x = 0;};

// second way is using modulus.
    shape2.pos_x = (shape2.pos_x + shape2.movement)% canvas.width;
```

Now if the shape is moving in the opposite direction i.e. from right to left I can use the first way using **if/else** statement as follow:

```
var shape3 = new Shape(5, 2);
var shape4 = new Shape(5, 4);

// first way to move a shape from right to left and return it to the canvas
if(shape3.pos_x > 0){
        shape3.pos_x -= shape3.movement;
}else {shape3.pos_x = canvas.width;};
```

My question is how can we use modulus to get same behavior for shape4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't actually have a modulo operator. The `%` is a remainder operator. You are stuck with the `if`-statement for the 4. case (or an extra field holding intermediate position which can be used with %, and then subtract that from width instead).

Comment: For negative value to the correct positive  `x = ((x % width) + width) % width;`  You can also use bit masking if you have width 127, 255, 511, 1023, 2047. or any of  `Math.pow(2, numBits)-1` for `numBits` 1 to 31. Eg for 255 `x &= 0xFF;`  or `x &= 255;`  masks out all bits above 8 and correctly returns positive values when negative.

Comment: And forgot  `x = (x<0 ? x+width : x)%width;`as long as neg val does not get greater than width. but you can add multiply `x = (x<0 ? x+width*100 : x)%width;`

Comment: Thank you both Blindman67 and K3N for the valuable feed backs..